# Azure Wordpress and Scalable Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, azure, scale

What is the difference between Azure WordPress and Azure Scalable WordPress? I cant see the difference except scalable wordpress allows you to select azure storage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic differences: Media is stored in a separate storage account and MySQL database is automatically scalable using ClearDB (master-master replica).

Regular Wordpress is single site single database only. For performance critical scenarios, scalable wordpress will handle a lot more concurrent requests. It also provides contingency.

Comment: It seems that the regular WordPress package uses ClearDB too now. This is a problem if you don't have a credit card associated with the account (e.g. MSDN subscription). They have a free tier but it seems very weak. Fortunately, Project Nami (basically Wordpress on MSSQL) is an alternative.

Comment: yup. actually trying cleardb for a while I concluded it's really really bad and I'd never use it in production environments. I'm building my own mysql servers when needed.

Comment: That seems in line with Kevin McCauley's sentiments. You should check out Project Nami tho, I ended up using it and everything seems to work pretty smoothly so far. Just don't use the marketplace package, rather create a blank website and set up a deployment from their github repository (http://projectnami.org/deploying-project-nami-to-windows-azure-web-sites/). They also have a "quick deploy" option (https://deploy.azure.com/?repository=https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami/tree/latest) but after creating my app through there I wasn't able to associate it with my existing service plan.

Answer (score 2):

Scalable WordPress on Azure (using cleardb) walks you through the steps to turn on auto-scaling technologies - using some expensive Azure VMs. You can find more information here: http://bit.ly/1Mi7bYE

I had a poor experience with Cleardb - their support was non-existent.  I"ve had much better luck with Bitnami's implementation of WordPress. However, you'll have to do some extra work to edit out their banners that "magically" appear on your WordPress site.

Comment: you know if it's easy to port from Wordpress to scalable WordPress. I'm mostly concerned about blog posts retaining their correct dates